# Error on accessing SharePoint 2010 Lists from a VB.NET app by Using WCF Data Services

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have a VB.NET application published to a server and basically I need to get all items from a SharePoint list and display them into a grid view. I'm trying to accomplish this by using WCF Data Services and getting the credentials as seen below. However I'm able to access this SharePoint list only when I test my application locally (localhost), when I publish to the server I no longer have authorization to do so, I then get the following error: (401) Unauthorized.

```
dc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

I've tried granting access to my server ID in SharePoint, but no success.

Anyone have any idea on how to give access for the server to access my SharePoint list?